# selenium code will run individually but not together

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I've never done any code/script/whatever it is i'm doing before and just learning along the way with ChatGPT. I'm trying to build a simple reservation script that reserves a certain time.

Everything works fine until I get to this last part:

```
next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[.//span[contains(@class, 'mat-button-wrapper') and contains(text(), 'Next')]]"))
)
next_button.click()

time.sleep(5)
finalize_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[.//span[contains(text(), 'Finalize Reservation')]]")
finalize_button.click()
```

This is the part that clicks "next" and then after it clicks "finalize reservation".

For some reason, if I run the entire code it won't work but if I run each line individually it will. I cannot figure out why that is. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds like a timing issue. I would remove the sleep and add a wait to the second click and see if that helps.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[.//span[contains(@class, 'mat-button-wrapper') and contains(text(), 'Next')]]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[.//span[contains(text(), 'Finalize Reservation')]]"))).click()
```

Comment: I've tried this already but the same thing happens where it works individually but not together. What happens is if I use element_to_be_clickable when the page loads for a brief second the element becomes clickable but it doesn't actually click. So the page loads, "finalize reservation" turns green for 1s before turning grey and then 2s later it turns green again... If I run this code together it will say the syntax is wrong but if I run it individually it's fine...

Comment: It's hard to fix this without seeing the page. I would suggest you put in a wait for the "finalize reservation" to be green, then add another wait for the "finalize reservation" to be gray, then add another wait for the "finalize reservation" to be green a second time and then click. The styles applied to the "finalize reservation" button are likely to be different or enabled/disabled, etc. Use that info to change the locator to fit the different states of the button for the 3 different waits.